# Check box function to paste value if check

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, paste

I am trying to make it so that if check box 82 is not checked then cell J39 is left blank but if it is checked the value is 3.8.  On the line "Sheet.Range("J39").PasteSpecial Paste = "3.8"" I am getting a error message 1004

```
Sub ChckBx_Deisel_Engines()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NSR FORM")
    If Sheet.Shapes("Check Box 82").ControlFormat.Value = 0 Then
        Sheet.Range("J39").PasteSpecial Paste = ""
    End

    ElseIf Sheet.Shapes("Check Box 82").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

        Sheet.Range("J39").PasteSpecial Paste = "3.8"
    End If
End Sub
```

Any Ideas on how to perform this function in a better way would also begreatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!  Here is the code I changed it to to get this function to work

```
 Sub Button82_Click()
     If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NSR FORM").Shapes("Check Box 82").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
     Range("J39").Value = "3.8"

     Else
     Range("J39").Value = ""
     End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NSR FORM")
    If Sheet.Shapes("Check Box 82").ControlFormat.Value = 0 Then
        Sheet.Range("J39").PasteSpecial Paste = "" :Exit sub <<< to exit direct from your project

    ElseIf Sheet.Shapes("Check Box 82").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

        Sheet.Range("J39").PasteSpecial Paste = "3.8"
    End If
End Sub
```